# What's the meaning of "dar" in "dar por supuesto"?

Tags: definiciones, verbos, expresiones

In an exercise I came across the following sentence:

> Mis colegas dan por supuesto que yo termino el trabajo.

I wonder about the expression *dan por supuesto*. I learned that *dar* is most frequently used as *to give* but I know that it may have different senses.

I would guess it just means *assume* and thus could be replaced with *suponen*:

> Mis colegas suponen que yo termino el trabajo.

Is that true? If yes, is the former sentence just a somewhat more formal way. What could be a proper translation? My guess would be *to proceed from the assumption*.
If no, what does this expression mean?

Answer (score 2):

The phrase *«dar por supuesto»* roughly translates as “to take as granted”.  Note that English “take out” or “take away” might have a similar meaning as *«dar»*, and yes *«dar por supuesto»* and *«suponer»* have a very similar meaning, with the subtle meaning shift you already guessed.

Other similar constructions with *«dar»*:

> *dar por hecho* (assume it is a fact)
>
> *dar por sentado* (agree or assume an agreement was done)
>
> *dar por muerto* (believe somebody is dead, left behind somebody assuming he/she is dead)
>
> *dar por perdido* (stop searching something, assume it is lost)

You probably get the common theme.

Comment: According to meanings 7 and 8 of [dar in RAE](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=dar), dar can mean "Convenir en una proposición" (agree in a proposition) or "Suponer, declarar, considerar". I think those meanings fit in this case.

Comment: Does "dar" here still have the literal meaning of "to give", i.e. do you say "to *give* something for granted" or "to *give* as a fact" or "to *give* someone as dead", or would you say that this sense of "dar" has nothing to do with the idea of "to give". I wonder because bilingual dictionaries put out a lot of translations for "dar" which do have nothing in common. I'm used to the fact that you mostly can derive from one meaning to another one, sometimes with a subtle shift, sometimes you need to take a great leap; but here it rather seems to be the opposite: to give - to take.

Comment: En mi experiencia he usado mucho las frases de ejemplo que tu utilizas, pero nunca `dan por supuesto` aunque la entiendo igual, lo que me suena rara

Comment: 'Dar por supuesto' is standard in Spain.